# How to replace HOME page from CodeIgniter to HOME Page of WordPress, other pages will stay from the CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a website developed in CodeIgniter, the current home page is also in COdeIgniter like
website.com/index.php (right now is a Page from CodeIgniter)

This HOME page is now requires to come from WordPress now, rest page link will work the same as earlier ie from CodeIgniter no Link URL changes.
WordPress
website.com/WordPress/index.php, Requires to work as => website.com/index.php (WordPress)

How do I replace the default HOME page from CodeIgniter to the HOME Page of WordPress (rest other pages will stay in CodeIgniter) ?

Comment: one easy method is copy the HTML from codeigniter and paste in wordpress template and make it front page.

Comment: That is okay, But my Question is how to make the URL's to work ie that Home Page from WordPress rest other pages will stay in CodeIgniter ?

Comment: I did this in .htaccess of root folder
-------------
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /wordpress/
--------------
The WordPress index becomes Home Page, but then other link from CodeIgniter pages doesn't work returns WP Page not found

Comment: post your htaccess file and folder structure. That is suspicious how you can have both WP and CI to share same folder.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /app/

    RewriteRule (.*?[A-Z]+.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L] 
    
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)&(.*)$ $1__-__$2 [N]

</IfModule>

Comment: @Alex above htaccess code is in root CI folder